# Question about app restart after its being destroyed

Tags: android, screen, kill, restart

When my application is killed due to being in the background for too long (Android freeing resources) or user using task killer or something similar, in onCreate I detect new application state and execute some initializations that my app needs to work properly. While this initialization is taking place, screen turn white and my app name is written in the top left corner (this is, I guess, what Android does by default). After 1-3 seconds, after all my app settings are recreated, my app screen shows up.

I am using my own header which is understandingly not shown during this "white phase".

My question is how can I customize this white screen? or at least I would be happy if I can remove my app name since it looks weird (positioned to left, no margins, etc..) and have only white screen.

I noticed that Gmail app has white screen only when similar happen.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe operations you have while initializing are too heavy?

Comment: More information about what exactly you're initializing would be helpful (e.g., whether you're making a connection with a server/database).  You may want to load this extra stuff in another Thread, separate from the UI thread.  If it is the UI that you're loading from another source, you might want to do it asynchronously.